# Inno Setup: Extending Windows default apps list

Tags: java, windows, installation, inno-setup

How is it possible to have listed my application on the Windows default apps list?

I have a special Java based video player application with an installer created by Inno Setup. I want my application to be listed on the selectable video players list on Windows 10 (I also don't know how to do it with older Windows versions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For generic information, see:

- [Registering an Application for Use with Default Programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/default-programs#registering-an-application-for-use-with-default-programs) on Microsoft Docs.
- [How do I add my application in the Default Programs list of Windows Vista/7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5542354/850848) on Stack Overflow

In Inno Setup, you implement this using [`[Registry]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection):

```
[Registry]
; Create the application capability key
; (The location of the key does not matter)
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program\Capability"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "ApplicationDescription"; \
    ValueData: "This is My Program that does stuff"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program\Capability"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "ApplicationName"; ValueData: "My Program"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue
; List of extensions the application supports
Root: HKLM; \
    Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program\Capability\FileAssociations"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: ".jpg"; ValueData: "MyProgram.JPEG"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue

; Add the capability key to list of registered applications
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\RegisteredApplications"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "My Program"; \
    ValueData: "Software\My Company\My Program\Capability"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue

; For each extension that the application supports
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgram.JPEG"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgram.JPEG"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "MyProgram JPEG"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgram.JPEG\DefaultIcon"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgram.JPEG\DefaultIcon"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\MyProg.exe,1"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgram.JPEG\Shell"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgram.JPEG\Shell\open"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgram.JPEG\Shell\open\Command"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MyProgram.JPEG\Shell\open\Command"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\MyProg.exe"" ""%1"""; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

---

In Inno Setup 6, you should modify the code as follows to support [non-administrative install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=admininstallmode):

1. Replace `HKLM` in the first block with `HKA`;
2. Replace `HKCR` with `HKA` and add the `Software\Classes\` prefix to the `Subkey`  in the second block.

---

[image: Set Default Programs]

[image: Set Program Associations]

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked beautifully for it. Thanks!

Comment: I eventually found that I needed to also add these lines so that files would actually appear to use the association created with the registry keys shown here: `Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.ABC\OpenWithProgids"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{#FileAssocKey}"; ValueData: ""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\Applications\ABC.exe\SupportedTypes"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".ABC"; ValueData: ""`