# Associate my QT application with video/image files in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, qt, inno-setup, windeployqt

I have developed QT application to view image/videos. I am deploying the application using `windeployqt` and have created `setup.exe` using Inno Setup tool.

I have already implemented code to show up image when opened through my app.

Now I want my application name to show up in *"Open with list"* whenever I click on image or video.

Has anyone idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [How to Include an Application in the Open With Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-include-an-application-on-the-open-with-dialog-box) – you have to create a registry values like these:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cpp\OpenWithProgids]
"VisualStudio.cpp.14.0"=""
```

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cpp.14.0]
@="C++ Source"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cpp.14.0\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcpackages\\VCProject.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cpp.14.0\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cpp.14.0\shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cpp.14.0\shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe\" /dde"
```

For an example how to create similar registry keys, see:
[Inno Setup: Extending Windows default apps list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36311624/850848)