# Associate file type/extension with a non-primary icon from an .exe file in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup, file-association

I am trying to get Inno Setup to associate three file types with my application and to assign an icon to each which have been embedded in my application.

I have edited this question now to reflect the Up-To-Date method as suggested.

I have added two icons to my main application, the Main application icon and Icon_1 and Icon_2 for file types which used by my Delphi application.  I used the Resources and Images Dialog under the Project menu to add them. The script I have used for this is below.

```
[Registry]
; Create the application capability key
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\{#MyAppPublisher}"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}\Capability"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ApplicationDescription"; ValueData: "Integrated Development Environment for Positron Compilers"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}\Capability"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ApplicationName"; ValueData: "{#MyAppName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

; List of extensions the application supports
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}\Capability\FileAssociations"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".bas"; ValueData: "{#MyAppName}.bas"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}\Capability\FileAssociations"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".inc"; ValueData: "{#MyAppName}.inc"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}\Capability\FileAssociations"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".psproj"; ValueData: "{#MyAppName}.psproj"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

; Add the capability key to list of registered applications
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\RegisteredApplications"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{#MyAppName}"; ValueData: "Software\#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}\Capability"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

; For each extension that the application supports
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.bas"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.bas"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppName} bas"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.bas\DefaultIcon"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.bas\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},1"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.bas\Shell"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.bas\Shell\open"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.bas\Shell\open\Command"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.bas\Shell\open\Command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}{#MyAppExeName}"" ""1"""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.inc"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.inc"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppName} inc"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.inc\DefaultIcon"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.inc\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},1"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.inc\Shell"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.inc\Shell\open"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.inc\Shell\open\Command"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.inc\Shell\open\Command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}{#MyAppExeName}"" ""1"""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.psproj"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.psproj"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppName} psproj"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.psproj\DefaultIcon"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.psproj\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},1"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.psproj\Shell"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.psproj\Shell\open"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.psproj\Shell\open\Command"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}.psproj\Shell\open\Command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}{#MyAppExeName}"" ""1"""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

Now the associations seem to have been lost.  I know I have two icons in the file because when I create a short cut I can choose from  either icon.  What do I need to do to get the correct icon on my files?

In the registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` under `.bas` I have:

```
DefaultIcon - not set
ProgWithIDs - not set
PersitentHandler - {5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace the `%1` with the 0-based index of the icon group within the .exe file.

```
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.bas\DefaultIcon"; ValueName: ""; \
  ValueType: string; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},ICON_GROUP_INDEX_GOES_HERE"; \
  Flags: uninsdeletevalue;
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type

---

For example, this will set `.isstest` icon to Inno Setup's document icon (the second icon in `Compil32.exe`):

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU ; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.isstest"; ValueData: "Icon Test"; \
  ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue;
Root: HKCU ; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.isstest\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; \
  ValueData: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6\Compil32.exe,1"; ValueName: ""; \
  Flags: uninsdeletevalue;
```

[image]

[image]

---

*Though this method for file association is obsolete. For an up-to-date method, see [Inno Setup: Extending Windows default apps list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36311624/850848). On the other hand, your icon problem is not related to that. In the new method, you specify the icon the same way, so you will have the same problem.*